# React Router hide content on specific routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've set up some routing using react-router which shows the Header, and Navigation Bars (SBNavigtion and SBTemplates) on every page. However, I also have a log-in and register page where I don't want to show the header, etc...

Is it possible to hide the header, and navigation bars on specific pages, or will I have to refactor all pages? Meaning, that I'll have to put the header and nav bars into each page individually so that it doesn't show up anymore on the log-in and register page?

```
        <div className="app">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header />
                <div className="app__structure">
                    <div className="app__structure-sidebar">
                        <SBNavigation />
                        <SBTemplates />
                    </div>
                    <div className="app__structure-routes">
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/log-in" element={<LoginPage />} />
                            <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
                            <Route path="/loading" element={<LoadingPage />} />
                            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                            <Route path="/leads" element={<LeadsPage />} />
                            <Route path="/leads/:id" element={<EditExistingLead />} />
                            <Route path="/leads/add-new" element={<AddNewLead />} />
                            <Route path="/templates" element={<TemplatesPage />} />
                            <Route path="/templates/:id" />
                            <Route path="/editor" element={<EditorPage />} />
                            <Route path="/review/:id" element={<ReviewPage />} />
                            <Route path="/settings/:id" element={<SettingsPage />} />
                            <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
```

Comment: You could consider nesting some routes to simplify that

Comment: Great! I didn't even know that it's possible to create different layouts just like that. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!